# UITableViewCell not being rendered correctly

Tags: c#, uitableview, xamarin.ios

We've created a TableViewController so that a user can enable/disable different notification types. After the initial load, everything is fine until the user scrolls to the bottom then back to the top and the first 1-2 table view cells aren't displaying correctly.

Example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/20eue.jpg

Typically deleting and recreating the view controller and xib/cs files fixes this, but was wondering if any one knows the cause of this.

Controller Code:

```
        public override nfloat GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
             return 305;
        }

        public override nint NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableView, nint section)
        {
            return _numRows;
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(Setting.Key) as Setting;
            if (cell == null)
            {
                var values = _settings.Where(s => s.Index == indexPath.Row).FirstOrDefault();

                cell = new Setting(values);

                var views = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib(Setting.Key, cell, null);

                cell = Runtime.GetNSObject(views.ValueAt(0)) as Setting;

            }

            cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
            cell?.PopulateData(_settings.Where(s => s.Index == indexPath.Row).FirstOrDefault(), this);

            return cell;
        }


        public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();
        }
```

Cell Code:

```
public partial class Setting : UITableViewCell     
{
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("Setting"); 
    public static readonly UINib Nib;         
    public SettingModel Values { get; set; }         

    static Setting()         
    {               
        Nib = UINib.FromName("Setting", NSBundle.MainBundle);         
    }           

    protected Setting(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) { }          

    public Setting() : base() {   }          

    public override void LayoutSubviews()         
    {              
        base.LayoutSubviews();         
    }          

    public void PopulateData(SettingModel values)          
    {             
        //logic...         

    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you share your sample so that I can test it on my side.I create a demo use your code and it works fine.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I've tried reproducing the issue in a small sample app, but can't. The main project is too large/contains sensitive data so that isn't an option.

Comment: Try to use static data and check if the issue happens.

Comment: Unfortunately the example above was with static data.

Comment: Did the issue appears on all device?

Comment: All emulators and several physical devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Visual Studio for Mac 8.6.5 resolved the issue.